# Counting Values in MuptiDimensional Array in Php

Tags: php, arrays

I currently have the following array:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user] => Name 
            [pwd] => jk

         )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [user] => Name 
            [pwd] => ew
            [city]=> pune
        )
    )
```

I am trying to count second index elements

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [user] => Name 
            [pwd] => ew
            [city]=> pune
        )
```

It must show count=2/3(if starts with 1)

Comment: place codes what you already tried

Comment: It is not clear enough.

Comment: I have just used count(arr[1]) it gives me total number of elements in array of index 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong then you need this.

```
$ararr = Array(Array
        (
            'user' => 'Name',
            'pwd' => 'jk'

         ), Array
        (
            'user' => 'Name',
            'pwd' => 'ew',
            'city'=> 'pune'
        )
    );

$count = '';

foreach($ararr as $key => $value){
    $count .= count($value).'/';
}

echo substr($count,0,-1); // 2/3
```

and using `array_map` function

```
$count = array_map(function ($t){ return $result = 'count is '.count($t);},$ararr);
print_r($count); //Array ( [0] => count is 2 [1] => count is 3 )
```